# Magento 1.9 i have added custom email template. need to preview customer before sending

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I have added custom emails template it is working fine preview and in admin side transnational email section after loading code.But i need to implement preview section in front-end so when i load email template code

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($templateId);
```

It's printing array as output.

Customer able to see preview before sending email.

Answer (score 0):

```
$template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($templateId);
    $templateProcessed = $template->getProcessedTemplate($vars, true);
    return $templateProcessed;
```

In $vars place need to pass variables array which you have added in template file for example i have below variable i am passing like the below

```
$vars = array('name' => $toname,
        'personal_message' => str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"<br>",$data['presonal_message']),
                  'custom_logo' => $custom_logo,
    );
```